# Noise filtering/cancellation via software while recording voice

Tags: noise, noise-reduction

While making videos at home, there is a considerable amount of ambient noise throughout the day (e.g. airplanes, cars honking, dogs barking, etc).  I know there are (software) tools that are capable of filtering out such noise while recording voice audio.  For example, Microsoft's "Teams" software has a digital/software filter that, when turned on, causes all of those sounds to be filtered out of the audio that is transmitted to others in the "Team" call. It does a flawless job of this, allowing essentially only voice audio to pass through.

However, I have yet to find what software would do this for a typical home video recording setup.  In my case, the hardware I have is:

- **Sound**: a Professional Scarlett Studio MIC, connected to a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2, which is then connected to a MacBook Pro.  The MacBook is running Ableton Live 11.
- **Video**: A Sony ZV-1F.

Honestly, I have yet to make my first video...but audio tests show that absolutely every ambient sound is mingled with my voice.

I am not looking for a solution of "go to a recording studio".  Also, I am not talking about playback of a recording (I am not looking for a noise-cancellation headset).  I am looking for software, presumably compatible with the above, which filters out the noise while the recording of my voice is in progress.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're working in mono, this becomes easy, using that dreaded misnomer… **AI**

Just record your soundtrack as normal, then throw the resulting file at [Adobe Enhance](https://podcast.adobe.com/enhance) (free but requires sign-up). It only takes wav or mp3. It *will* take stereo but gives you mono back.
Tadahh. Clean audio track.

Honestly, it's nearly put me out of a job :\

There's also a [Mic Check](https://podcast.adobe.com/miccheck) tool, which I haven't yet tried.

<sup>BTW, the kind of routines that Teams et al use is 'clever' but pretty low bandwidth/complexity. You wouldn't want to use it for broadcast</sup>